# Trying to make a !ping command that shows ms but I get this error

Tags: discord.js

When I run it, the bot runs as it should with the commands I added, but when I do !ping in the chat it gives me an error in the terminal

This is my code

```
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const Command = require("../Structures/Command.js");

module.exports = new Command({
    name: "ping",
    description: "Shows the ping of the bot!",

    async run(message, args, client) {
        message.reply(`Ping: ${Client.ws.ping} ms.`);
    },
});
```

This is the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ping' of undefined
    at Command.run (C:\Users\Aly\Desktop\SpidBot\src\Commands\ping.js:9:36)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aly\Desktop\SpidBot\src\index.js:42:10)
    at Client.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Aly\Desktop\SpidBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:23:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Aly\Desktop\SpidBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Aly\Desktop\SpidBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:345:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Aly\Desktop\SpidBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:443:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Aly\Desktop\SpidBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:300:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Aly\Desktop\SpidBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
```

I dont really get what im supposed to do, when I remove the ".ws" (on line 9) the command works but it tells me "undefined ms" in the chat

Comment: It is a typo... `Client` -> `client`. This is your second typo question, double check please before asking at SO...

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry, I'm just a bit new to js. I'll check next time, thanks! (btw it worked ty!)

Answer (score 1):

try this for your ping command, i was trying the same thing you were just doing so i tried this instead and it worked

const { Client } = require("discord.js");

const Command = require("../Structures/Command.js");

module.exports = new Command({
name: "ping",
description: "Shows the ping of the bot!",

```
async run(message, args, client) {
        message.channel.send("Pinging...").then(m =>{
        
          let ping = m.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp;

        // Basic embed
          let embed = new MessageEmbed()
          .setAuthor(`Your ping is ${ping}`)
          .setColor("RANDOM")
          
          // Then It Edits the message with the ping variable embed that you created
          m.edit({ embeds: [embed]})
      });
},
```

});